# C++ Undefined Symbol error in OSX10.7.4

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clang

The following call from the command line, `clang++  vcfaltcount.cpp -o vcfac`, produces the following error/warnings

```
>In file included from vcfaltcount.cpp:1:
./Variant.h:86:5: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}

>Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "split(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&,                    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced           from:
  _main in ccGOdUhH.o
  vcf::VariantCallFile::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >&)in ccGOdUhH.o
 "vcf::VariantCallFile::getNextVariant(vcf::Variant&)", referenced from:
  _main in ccGOdUhH.o
  "vcf::VariantCallFile::parseHeader()", referenced from:
  vcf::VariantCallFile::openFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,       std::allocator<char> >&)in ccGOdUhH.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There are many other posts on "undefined symbols for such&such architecture," and I have attempted to use those suggestions to successfully compile.

I think the problem may arise from the header file, variant.h. In the API from which the source code came there was a corresponding variant.cpp file that defined the functions, which were only declared in variant.h. I moved those definitions into variant.h. Any thoughts on what I may be missing? I can provide the header if need be, but it is long. Thanks.

Comment: And what happens if, perchance, you do not move the definitions from the .cpp to the .h?

Comment: The .cpp from which the functions came was actually not included in this build. The functions were declared in the current .h but they were not declared in said file or the .cpp I am using presently. Regardless, when I included those definitions the same errors occurred. I was not clear in stating that my past attempts yielded no improvement.

Comment: Have you used the library .cpp file in the clang invocation too?

Comment: Adding the other .cpp file to the invocation resulted in the same errors.